# Chrome Extension - onMessageExternal undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to build an extension that interacts with an internal app, and I'm looking at the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage%20documentation) for the external messaging stuff, but whenever I try and access `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener`, I get an error saying `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` is undefined. Same thing for `onConnectExternal`

**manifest,json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":           "My Extension",
    "description":    "My Desc",
    "version":        "0.2",

    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [
            "http://*.mysite.com/*"
        ]
    },

    "author": "Aaron Scherer",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*.mysite.com/*"
            ],
            "js":      ["js/script.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**js/script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function( request, sender, sendResponse ) {
        debugger;
        console.debug( request  );
        console.debug( sender );
        console.debug( sendResponse  );
} );
```

**website's js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage( 'myextid', { test: 'test' } );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` is only available in the background page, not in a content script. If you want to use this api to talk to content scripts you could relay the messages through the background page.

Another alternative is to use the standard `window.postMessage`. If you set a listener for `'message'` with `window.addEventListener` in your content script you can receive messages sent from the page, and vice versa.